# Use $.each into json

Tags: jquery, json, contextmenu

This code gets users from my DB :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/liste_users.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(retour_php) {
        console.log(retour_php);
        liste_users = retour_php;
    }                           
});
```

`console.log` shows me all users.

I would like to know how can I loop into users to create my json with this code:

```
"items": {
    $.each(liste_users, function(index, value) {
        index : { "name": + " " + value }   
    });
}
```

Missing after property id is shown

Comment: That is not valid JSON. And I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you wat to *gerenate* JSON?

Comment: Are you trying to create a new object from the returned JSON? Your second code example contains so many syntax errors it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So what's `retour_php`? is it a `JSON` or something else..?

Comment: I need to create a json objet from the reply I get in my $.ajax method.  The target is to use it in contextmenu ("id","user").

Comment: @user3553866 yea, the question is, what do you get as the reply of ajax request. in can be many things.

Comment: I get this from the ajax reply [Object { user="1"}, Object { user="Pierre Vanamen"}, Object { user="2"}, Object { user="Cedric Delarue"}, Object { user="3"}, Object { user="Benjamin Langlais"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
var jsonObjArr=[];
$.each(liste_users, function(i, e) {
    jsonObjArr.push({'user':e});
});
```

And it will contain values in json like:

```
[{'user':'abc'},{'user':'def'}]
```

if thats what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I obtain a good format, but how can I use my objet to add items in context menu ?  "sousmenu"

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to add all the jsonarr values to right click or what?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the users for the right click (context menu)

Comment: I will recommend using http://s-yadav.github.io/contextMenu.html context-menu js.. have built in ability to take json inputs.

Comment: I cannot change the method I'm using because I'm modifiying the existing code.  It is impossible to me to change the method.  Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: May be I can help, if you show me how you are inserting values to context menu.. if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use map than each in this case.

```
var obj = {
    "item": $.map(liste_users, function(value, index) {
        return {
            "id": index,
            "name": value
        }; 
    })
};
```